# Query for regular expression - oracle DB

Tags: regex, database, oracle

I am trying to get all the name which has special char and numbers in it. I want to know if there is a better way of writing this query.  Thanks

```
select Name from TABLE1
WHERE NAME  LIKE '%-%'
   OR NAME  LIKE '%$%'
   OR NAME  LIKE '%4%' etc
```

Comment: mysql OR oracle not both

Comment: As already said, tag dbms used, since the answer will be product specific!

Comment: is it mysql? or oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Name FROM Test WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(Name,'(-|$|4)');
```

The | (OR or Alternation) operator allows the expression to return true if the value contains an '-' OR an '$' OR an '4' etc.

Comment: Did you mean, `regexp_like`?

Comment: You could do SELECT Name FROM TABLE1 WHERE NAME REGEXP_LIKE (NAME,'(-|$|4)')

Comment: The character list in your match pattern will not work with the `like` operator. Have you tried it?

Comment: That is better.  Perhaps you could provide an explanation of the alternation operator?

Comment: Actually parenthesis define a group.  You regex fails and returns the original string. Be sure to test it with valid names.

Answer (score 0):

Use square brackets to define a character class.  Also a full regex to anchor the pattern to the beginning of the string, any number of any characters before a character class consisting of a dash or a 4 or a dollar sign then any number of any characters anchored to the end of the string:

```
SQL> with tbl(name) as (
  2    select 'efs' from dual
  3    union
  4    select 'abc-' from dual
  5    union
  6    select 'a4bd' from dual
  7    union
  8    select 'gh$dll' from dual
  9    union
 10    select 'xy5zzy' from dual
 11  )
 12  select name from tbl
 13  where regexp_like(name, '^.*[-|$|4].*$');

NAME
------
a4bd
abc-
gh$dll

SQL>
```